# Как сделать чтобы при выводе списка из студентов к каждому из пунктов добавлялся порядковый номер

Tags: c++

Я сейчас пытаюсь выучить структурированные типы данных и моё задание звучит так:

> Ввести в компьютер информацию о студентах группы: фамилия, порядковый
>   номер, получает стипендию или нет, средний бал за сессию. Вывести на
>   экран список студентов, которые получают стипендию.

Как сделать так, чтобы при показе количества студентов был подпункт(порядковый номер) в каждом пункте списка?

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Student;
void Sort(int count, Student *st);

struct Student
{
    static const int number = 1;
    int bal;
    string surname;
    bool stepa;
public:
    Student()
    {
        bal  = 0;
        surname = "";
        stepa = false;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        cout << "Фамилия: " << surname << "\t Порядковый номер: " << number  << "\tЕсть ли стипендия: " << stepa <<"\tРейтинговый бал"<<bal << endl;
    }

    void SetAll()
    {
        number++; 
        cout << "Введите фамилию: ";
        cin >> surname; 
        cout << "Введите Есть ли стипендия: ";
        cin >> stepa; 
        cout << "Введите рейт бал: ";
        cin >> bal; 
        cout << " " << endl;
    }

    void print(){
        cout << "Порядковый номер: "<< number << endl;
        cout << "Фамилия: "<<surname<<endl;
        cout << "Есть ли стипендия: "<<stepa<<endl;
        cout << "Рейтинговый бал студента: "<< bal<<endl;
        cout << " "<<endl;
    }

    void printb() {
        if(stepa) {
            cout << "Порядковый номер: "<< number << endl;
            cout << "Фамилия: " << surname << endl;
            cout << "Есть ли стипендия: "<<stepa<<endl;
            cout << "Рейтинговый бал студента: "<< bal<<endl;
            cout << " "<<endl;
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int countStudents = 0;
    cout << "Введите количество студентов: ";
    cin >> countStudents;

    Student *arr;
    arr = new Student[countStudents];

    for(int p=0; p<countStudents; p++){
        arr[p].SetAll();
    }

    for(int p=0; p<countStudents; p++){
        arr[p].printb();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У Вас же есть массив со студентами? И номер студента - это индекс в массиве? Значит вопрос сводится к тому, чтобы в Ваши функции `print()` как-то передать этот индекс из цикла. Например, Вы можете просто добавить входным параметром в функции печати этот самый номер и при печати его туда передавать. Ну а чтобы номер не печатался когда нет массива, можно сделать ему (параметру) значение по умолчанию (скажем -1) и проверять этот номер перед печатью.. Кстати, таким же образом (через параметр) можно передавать и указание (флаг) про печать по условию со стипендией и обойтись только одной функцией.

Answer (score 0):

добавь переменную int number2; а в конструктор код number2 = number++; и используй number2 и используй number2 как порядковый номер

Answer (score 0):

Киль пишете на c++, пишите в c++ стиле. Переопределите оператор вывода <<. 
Пример тут:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019
А потом вместо `arr[p].printb();` пишите
`std::cout << p + 1 << " " << arr[p] << std::endl;`
 Аналогично переопределить >> для ввода, вместо SettAll().